# How to get an icon-only controlgroup inside the header?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I need more than one mini-sized button inside a header Toolbar, but they appears smaller as they should be, and i'm not able to style this icon-only buttons inside a controlgroup like a single icon-only button, which works - instead - as expected, like in the JQM Demos.

Which JQM classes should i use for this task? Do i need here a custom wrapperClass?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div data-role="page" id="page-one">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
      <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" class="ui-mini ui-btn-left">
        <button class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-tag ui-btn-icon-notext">Button</button>
        <button class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-user ui-btn-icon-notext">Button</button>
      </div>
      <h3>Page One</h3>
      <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" class="ui-mini ui-btn-right">
        <button class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-tag ui-btn-icon-notext">Button</button>
        <button class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-user ui-btn-icon-notext">Button</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your buttons to link buttons (anchor tag) and it works as you have it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
  <style>
div.ui-mini .ui-btn {
  width: 26px;
}
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div data-role="page" id="page-one">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
      <div class="ui-mini ui-btn-left">
        <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-tag ui-btn-icon-notext">Icon only</a>
        <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-user ui-btn-icon-notext">Icon only</a>
      </div>
      <h3>Page One</h3>
      <div class="ui-mini ui-btn-right">
        <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-tag ui-btn-icon-notext">Icon only</a>
        <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-user ui-btn-icon-notext">Icon only</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: great ezanker, sorry if this wasn't enough clear in my question, i need it round, just like a single button. `ui-corner-all` applies the needed `border-radius:1em` for one single stand-alone button, but i'm not able to get the same for two buttons inside a `controlgroup`.

Comment: @deblocker, In that case, don't use a controlgroup. Change them to regular DIVs. I have updated my answer with the change

Comment: you gave me the idea, as i will do it dynamically - instead of styling i will do  `$("#page-one [data-role=header] [data-role=controlgroup]").controlgroup("destroy");` and .`enhanceWithin()` to restore the corners. many THX