# Trouble with button position in header

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

i'm having trouble with the position of a button, i'm trying to align to the right but nothing works with that. If someone would help me i'll be proud. The code from my page with is below

```
<div data-role="page" id="pag_busc_cliente">
<div data-role="header">
<div class="btn_head_buscar_cliente">
<a id="btn_Volver_Busqueda_Cliente" data-role="button" class="ui-btn btnvolver ui-icon-back ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all ui-mini ui-shadow"></a>
<a id="btn_Crear_Cliente" data-role="button" class="ui-btn crearcliente ui-icon-user ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-right ui-mini ui-shadow">Crear Cliente</a>
</div>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
<input type="search" name="buscar_cliente" id="buscar_cliente" placeholder="Busque Cliente" value="">
</div>
<div data-role="footer">
</div>
</div>
```

and here is the css code i'm trying to put

```
.crearcliente
{
margin-left: 3px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This aproach uses position:relative on the parent element and position:absolute on the component you want to move right.

https://codesandbox.io/s/ug9ov?fontsize=14

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap Your left and right button groups inside the built-in classes `ui-btn-left` and `ui-btn-right`:

```
<div data-role="page" id="pag_busc_cliente">
  <div data-role="header">
    <div class="ui-btn-left ui-mini">
      <a id="btn_Volver_Busqueda_Cliente" class="ui-btn ui-icon-back ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all ui-shadow"></a>
    </div>
    <h4 class="ui-title"></h4>
    <div class="ui-btn-right ui-mini">
      <a id="btn_Crear_Cliente" class="ui-btn ui-icon-user ui-corner-all ui-shadow">Crear Cliente</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">
    <input type="search" name="buscar_cliente" id="buscar_cliente" placeholder="Busque Cliente" value="" />
  </div>
  <div data-role="footer">
    <h4 class="ui-title"></h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

BTW, You can wrap also the `ui-mini` class.

Here is another top-quality reference: [How to get an icon-only controlgroup inside the header?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44071391/4845566)